# Steps for Creating Login api using django rest framework by Token Authentication

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create login api with LoginSerializer and LoginAPIView using django-rest-auth, can anyone please explain the steps on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Its quite simple, following are the steps:

First Create a serializer class **UserLoginSerializer** in serializers file and include following codes there

```
class UserLoginSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ('id', 'username','title','email')
```

Second, Make a class in Views and include following codes

```
class Login(APIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def post(self,request):
        email = request.data.get('email',None)
        password = request.data.get('password',None)
        if email and password:
            user_obj = Account.objects.filter(email__iexact=email)
            if user.exists() and user.first().check_password(password):
                user = UserLoginSerializer(user_obj)
                data_list = {}
                data_list.update(user.data)
                return Response({"message": "Login Successfully", "data":data_list, "code": 200})
            else:
                message = "Unable to login with given credentials"
                return Response({"message": message , "code": 500, 'data': {}} )
        else:
            message = "Invalid login details."
            return Response({"message": message , "code": 500, 'data': {}})
```

Comment: Thank you Pallavi, how would you implement a Token Authentication on this view?

Comment: You can generate a token and can save or update in  db if user exists. For generating token please visit this page 
http://www.tomchristie.com/rest-framework-2-docs/api-guide/authentication